# How to modify the values of variables in one python file from another?

Tags: python, python-module

I want to create a python program where I can modify the values in a program and use the modified values in another program.
Here's an example:

**vars.py**

```
a = 20
b = 30
x = 20+30
```

**func.py**

```
import vars
def changevalues():
    vars.a = 40
    vars.b = 50
```

**main.py**

```
import vars
import func

func.changevalues()
print(vars.x)
```

When I run **main.py**, the output I want is 90, but it adds up 20 and 30 and the output is 50.

Comment: Your code is printing `vars.x` which you set to `20+30` in `vars.py`. It doesn't matter what you set `a` and `b` to when `x` is still set to 50. Also worth mentioning that you are simply calling print on `vars.x` so whatever that is set to is what's going to print. The function isn't affecting anything.

Comment: ...note that what @Jackie explains would be true even if the third line of your "vars.py" file were `x = a + b`.  `x` is set when the file is imported.  So later changes to `a` and/or `b` would not change the value of `x` in that case either.

Comment: @CryptoFool, is there any way that the value of `x` will also be changed along with `a` and `b`?

Comment: @BitanSarkar You declared `x` as an `int`, which is immutable. So the only way to change it is by assigning it to another value. If you want it to track changes in `a` and `b`, then `x` needs to be a callable (a function, for example), a [class property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), or a mutable type, like a list, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The only change you need to make to your code is to change the existing variable `x` from within your function.  So, for example, add just one line to `changevalues()`:

```
def changevalues():
    vars.a = 40
    vars.b = 50
    vars.x = vars.a + vars.b
```

Then run `main.py` and your result will be:

```
90
```